# How do I keep a shell (ssh) connection alive?

Tags: shell, ssh

I'm using Moba XTerm to connect via SSH to my web server. There, I run npm scripts that watch files until they change, and then recompile them.

Every 10-15 mins my connection times out, presumably for security. This is a shared host, so I am limited in what I can control in Apache.

Is there any way I can get my connection to stay alive?

Comment: I doubt it's for security. You can set up `mosh` for long term persistent connections, but it's slightly tricky (though possible) to install it on the host when you don't have root access. Note that an alternative is to run the programs in `tmux` or `screen` to have them stay open when you get disconnected. You can then at any time reconnect and reattach them if you want to interact with them, otherwise you can just leave them running indefinitely

Comment: Thanks @thatotherguy - it's not clear, though, what steps I would take to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try SSH keepalive, for MobaXterm follow:

https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/documentation.html#6_8_4

Comment: please close off-topic questions.

Comment: Thanks @JGK, this is actually what I was looking for - it's perfect, at least for Moba XTerm.

Answer (score 1):

Usually for long running or critical actions, you use `screen` (or tmux) on the server, which should be installed in almost all Linux servers. Some distributions also come with `byobu` wich is basically a extensively more "userfriendly" configured version of one of these two (with a status bar, help texts etc.).

`screen` runs in its own process and continues running if the ssh connections dies. Next time you log in (via ssh) you then 'reconnect' to the screen session. Multiple screen sessions running multiple different processes (in so called screens/windows) are possible.

While the key shortcuts and the thinking behind might feel a bit strange at the beginning, it will soon become a tool that you are familiar with and use often.

To learn more, you can read the manpage (`man screen`) and search the internets (e.g. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Screen , but I am sure there are more illustrated examples out there).

Comment: please close off-topic questions.

Comment: @jww Please clarify whom you are addressing. On the one hand I understand the off-topicness (e.g. asking for administrative help rather than programming), but on the other hand the issue in the question can be considered a typical programming related issue, too, imho.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not the connection. If you just want to keep the script running all the time, you could run your npm script in daemon status with following commands:

```
# nohup npm run &> output.log &
# tail -f output.log
```

If your connection is broken, your npm script would not be killed, and the output will be saved in output.log. So you can reconnect to your server and use `tail` command to get your log